# WebDAV query trouble - unable to read body of e-mail

Tags: c#, email, outlook, c#-2.0, webdav

Our group (corporate environment) needs to monitor a couple of faceless accounts' Outlook inbox for specific types of bounced e-mails.

**WebDAV** (using C# 2.0) is one of the paths we've traveled and we're almost there, except for one minor problem: we're getting the response below for the e-mail body element

```
<a:propstat>
  <a:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Resource Not Found</a:status> 
- <a:prop>
  <a:htmldescription /> 
  <a:textdescription /> 
  </a:prop>
  </a:propstat>
```

The only real commonality is that it only happens on messages that our Exchange server is returning to us as "Undeliverable".  Note:  All other e-mails come across just fine.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like undeliverable messages in Exchange have a content-type of "multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status". Probably because they don't have a body, just a summary of the delivery attempt which can actually all be gathered from the Headers of the message. Perhaps the WebDAV access (I don't have access to an OWA account right now to check) doesn't know what to do with that, i.e. is just thinks the e-mails don't have a body.